# Tailwind CSS not applying certain styles

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I have created a next.js app using the tailwind starter repo provided in the next.js documentation and tailwind was working well. However I recently ran into an issue where certain tailwind classes stopped working , specifically any class related to colors.

I have already tried running npm -i again, but no change occurred.

postcss.config

```
// If you want to use other PostCSS plugins, see the following:
// https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    colors:{
      transparent:"transparent",
      current:"currentColor",
      primary:{
        superlight:"#FFFFFF",
        light:"#FFF8F0",
        DEFAULT:"#FFEBD1",
        dark:"#978F85"
      },
      secondary:{
        light:"#EFEFEF",
        DEFAULT:"#A0A0A0",
        dark:"#26221D"
      }
  },
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

_app.js

```
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: Only the colors that you define in `theme.colors` will be available to you. If you want to extend the default colors use `theme.extend.colors` instead.

Comment: You're using `jit` mode. So are you watching changes? If you can't see newly added classes in action, your output css file does not contain those css classes. So you need to watch changes or compile your css after every change manually. Also you are not extending theme colors, you're overriding them. This is another issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `extend` the theme, not overwrite it.

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  purge: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        transparent: "transparent",
        current: "currentColor",
        primary: {
          superlight: "#FFFFFF",
          light: "#FFF8F0",
          DEFAULT: "#FFEBD1",
          dark: "#978F85"
        },
        secondary: {
          light: "#EFEFEF",
          DEFAULT: "#A0A0A0",
          dark: "#26221D"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {}
  },
  plugins: []
};
```

Also, keep in mind that JIT mode is still not completely bug-free. If you experience issues like that again, try restarting your server.